# File Uploader with Progress Bar for .NET

Tags: .net, file-upload

I need to develop a file uploaded for my web app.

My current uploader is iframe based async uploader w\o real progress bar. But I am looking for a file uploader with these reqs (c#, asp.net):

- Must allow single file and multiple (say 5) file upload
- Must allow uploading large files
  (single video file) and images
  (multiple images)
- Must show a real progress bar like the FaceBook or gmail uploader
- Better be light weight
- Easy to implemenent and easy to plugin
- Easy API, jQuery API for accessing file properties
- File type and size control during upload
- Not Java Based

If there is anything free, I will highly consider that.

Worst case, I am ready to pay a price for license (if I buy)

Please help me. Thanks for reading

Comment: Did this question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562696/asp-net-multiple-upload-with-jquery-multiple-file-upload-plugin Or maybe this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135123/how-can-i-get-gmail-like-file-uploads-for-my-web-app

Comment: Thanks Richard. I will go over these links

Answer (score 0):

I have used this with moderate success, i'm not sure it 100% satisfies all your conditions, but its probably worth a look:

http://ajaxuploader.com/

Comment: why you said you had moderate success? It has some specific issues that you faced? It seems good. Also it is not free which is fine for now.

Comment: It works, but it's not the nicest one I've seen, and another developer on my team had a hard time doing some customizations we wanted with it...

Comment: This is not free